# dplyr rename equivalent in plyrmr

Tags: r, hadoop, rename, dplyr

Is there a `dplyr::rename` equivalent in `plyrmr`?

I have tried doing this:

```
magic.wand(rename)
```

and

```
magic.wand(rename,mergeable=TRUE,vectorized=TRUE)
```

but it does not solve my problem for this code:

```
input(mtcars) %|% bind.cols(temp=mpg/gear) %|% rename(nice=temp)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
input(mtcars) %|% bind.cols(temp=mpg/gear) %|% 
gapply(function(x) {
  names(x)[names(x)=="temp"] <- "nice"
  return(x)
})
```

But I still would like to know why the magic wand doe not work in this case.